Confusion about output sizes of GAN
I am trying to understand a code, I am confused about the test cells. When i am printing the shape of the output it is hidden_output.shape =(num_test, 20, 4, 4), test_hidden_block_stride(hidden_output).shape) == (num_test, 20, 10, 10) and Gen_output.shape=(num_test, 1,28,28) for Mnist dataset. I am trying to understand how the sizes are being calculated here. Any help will be greatly appreciated!
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, z_dim=10, im_chan=1, hidden_dim=64):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.z_dim = z_dim
        # Build the neural network
        self.gen = nn.Sequential(
            self.make_gen_block(z_dim, hidden_dim * 4),
            self.make_gen_block(hidden_dim * 4, hidden_dim * 2, kernel_size=4, stride=1),
            self.make_gen_block(hidden_dim * 2, hidden_dim),
            self.make_gen_block(hidden_dim, im_chan, kernel_size=4, final_layer=True),
        )
def make_gen_block(self, input_channels, output_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0 ,final_layer=False):
        # Build the neural block
        layers = []
        layers.append(nn.ConvTranspose2d(input_channels, output_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding, output_padding=padding))
        if not final_layer:
            layers.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(output_channels))
            layers.append(nn.ReLU(True))
        else:
            layers.append(nn.Tanh())
        
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)
# Testing
gen = Generator()
num_test = 100
# Test the hidden block
test_hidden_noise = get_noise(num_test, gen.z_dim)
test_hidden_block = gen.make_gen_block(10, 20, kernel_size=4, stride=1)
test_uns_noise = gen.unsqueeze_noise(test_hidden_noise)
hidden_output = test_hidden_block(test_uns_noise)
# Check that it works with other strides
test_hidden_block_stride = gen.make_gen_block(20, 20, kernel_size=4, stride=2)
test_final_noise = get_noise(num_test, gen.z_dim) * 20
test_final_block = gen.make_gen_block(10, 20, final_layer=True)
test_final_uns_noise = gen.unsqueeze_noise(test_final_noise)
final_output = test_final_block(test_final_uns_noise)
# Test the whole thing:
test_gen_noise = get_noise(num_test, gen.z_dim)
test_uns_gen_noise = gen.unsqueeze_noise(test_gen_noise)
gen_output = gen(test_uns_gen_noise)

I am trying to calculate the sizes from the formula by hand. I am just seeing different kernel sizes and strides and padding. not sure which values to use.

The only layers that change the output shape in your Generator network are the nn.ConvTranspose2d layers. The other layers, including BatchNorm2d, nn.ReLU, nn.Tanh have no impact on the output shapes. Thus, your question essentially boils down to how to calculate the output shape of a nn.ConvTranspose2d layer?
Here is how: given input tensors with shape (N, C_in, H_in, W_in), where N, C_in, H_in and W_in are the input batch size, channel, height, and width respectively, you can calculate the output tensor shape (N, C_out, H_out, W_out) using the following formula:
H_out = (H_in − 1) × stride[0] − 2 × padding[0] + dilation[0] × (kernel_size[0] − 1) + output_padding[0] + 1
W_out = (W_out − 1) × stride[1] − 2 × padding[1] + dilation[1] × (kernel_size[1] − 1) + output_padding[1] + 1

Where the parameters including C_in, C_out, kernel_size, stride, dilation, padding,... are set when defining the nn.ConvTranspose2d layer. You can read more about each of them on PyTorch documentations.
For example your test input is (num_test, 10, 1, 1), and your test_hidden_block layer has C_in=10, C_out=20, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(1, 1), padding=(0, 0), so:
H_out = (1 - 1) × 1 - 2 × 0 + 1 × (4 - 1) + 0 + 1 = 4
W_out = (1 - 1) × 1 - 2 × 0 + 1 × (4 - 1) + 0 + 1 = 4

Hence the output shape of this layer is (num_test, 20, 4, 4).
I find the visual representations of this blog on transposed convolutions very helpful.
